# ElasticSearch/ElasticCloud Alert Creation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

I am a newbie in Elastic in general and currently I am trying to manage our alerts for CPU/Disk/Memory in Elastic Cloud. I can create the alerts manually just fine, but that takes a huge amount of time and if we migrate I want to be able to create the alerts in some automated way. In the past I have worked with Azure and created alerts with Az PowerShell and etc, so I am searching how to automate the alert creation for our infrastructure in Elastic Cloud. I went through the documentation for Alerts [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/alerting-apis.html). But, im not sure I understand how to use the API to actually do this.

Is there a way to automate lets say creation of CPU alerts for 10 different hosts that we monitor with Elastic ? Is using the API the only way and are there any materials other than the official documentation that can help me achieve this? And am I even on the correct path? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share knowledge of using Azure Monitor where you can connects the resources to Azure Monitor and manage the Alerts. Alerts can send you an email or call a web hook when some metric (for example database size or CPU usage) reaches the threshold. There are several ways to create Alerts- using [Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-classic-portal#with-azure-portal), [Command Line Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-classic-portal#with-azure-cli), Powershell and [Azure Monitor Rest API.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alert-rules) Hope it will help you.

Even you can automate alerts using [Azure Automation runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-alert-metric#:%7E:text=1%20Launch%20the%20Azure%20Automation%20service%20in%20the,already%20defined%20and%20associated%20with%20your%20Automation%20account.) with Mertic Alerts. where can automate the alerts according to the customized dimensional values and once  the Alert criteria met it can even send an mail.

Comment: Hi @IpsitaDash-MT, Thank you, but I am well aware how to work with the Cloud native alerts and monitoring. This specific topic and question is related to Elastic Search and Elastic Cloud Monitoring and how to automate alerts rather than creating XX number of alerts manually. So the valid answer would be, if such automation can be done in Elastic Search/Cloud, if yes then how and with what tools => API or any automation tool or script. Currently the above information that you provided is not helpful for this.

Comment: Thank you for the update @KristianKanchev, I will try to find more appropriate answer to it